# Insert pandas dataframe into mongodb

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pymongo

reindexing dataframe to dict,And I want to insert data into mongodb new Collection?
Dataframe:

```
df = mydf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='timestamp', freq='5Min'))['value'].apply(lambda x: x[x!='-1'].count())
k = df.reset_index().T.to_dict().values()
print(k)

p={}
p[name] = k #adding new key into json
print(p)

db.col8.insert_many(k)  #inserting data into mongodb
```

Error:

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

Expected Result:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a4f07559799980e94717c69"),
        "name": "abc"
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2018-01-03T12:00:00Z"),
        "value" : 0
}
```

And insert should not be duplicate it should do upsert.So how to frame the mongodb query for insertion/update using pandas dataframe?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm interested in how pandas interacts with MongoDB, and will look at a solution this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

For future, you always need to convert variable types from pandas to simple Python types: `dict`, `list`, `str`, `int`, `float`, etc. All `numpy`/`pandas` types will raise an exception.

Fixed code, I think that you wanted to insert `p` not `k` variable to database:

```
df = mydf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(key='timestamp', freq='5Min'))['value'].apply(lambda x: x[x!='-1'].count())
k = df.reset_index().T.to_dict().values()
print(k)

p={}
p[name] = k #adding new key into json
print(p)

db.col8.insert_many(p)  #inserting data into mongodb
```